# how does configure look for working mpi and fftw3 libararies?

Tags: mpi, configure

I am trying to compile Blochlibs-1.2 libraries on Ubuntu 15.04 (32 bit). Ihave successfully compiled fftw3 and mpi libraries which all ended up in `/usr/local/lib` and `usr/local/include`. mpicc is in the path and LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set correctly. when I run configure like this:

```
./configure --with-mpi=/usr/local --with-fftw=/usr/local
```

then i get this error:

> checking for functioning MPI library ... configure: error: couldn't
>   find mpi library for --with-mpi

How does the configure file search for the libraries?

Thanks,

Z

Comment: Have you tried `./configure --with-mpi=/usr/local/include --with-fftw=/usr/local/lib` ?

Comment: well that one did not work but I checked and the includes are in the include folder and libraries are in the lib folder I need both for compilation. I also tried to separate them in usr/local/mpi/include & usr/local/mpi/lib &usr/local/fftw3/include & usr/local/fftw3/lib and give the the configure the option /usr/local/mpi/ & usr/local/fftw3 but it is still failing to find working libraries for both fftw3 & mpi. I do not know why though since they are both there both shared and static libraries.